# Bash script: need to pass variable expansion result to another script with double quotes

Tags: bash, quotes

I have an executable compiled from some go code that can be executed as follows:

```
./goclient -id 10 -env test -args "testarg -testflag_in_args blah blah2"
```

Essentially, the args flag takes in a long string of multiple arguments, so the input needs to be double quoted as above.

I have another script that executes the aforementioned executable, like this:

```
./goclient -id 10 -env test -args "${config_options[@]}"
```

The problem is that after `config_options` gets expanded, I'm not able to wrap the variable expansion result in double quotes. So the executable thinks that only `testarg` is passed in as input to `-args`, and `-testflag` gets treated as a flag to goclient, which goclient doesn't recognize and complains.

How can I wrap the expansion of `"${config_options[@]}"` in double quotes to pass to `-args`? I've tried various things like escaping double quotes around it already. Using `eval` works, but I've been told not to use it due to security issues. Thanks!

Comment: Try: `./goclient -id 10 -env test -args "${config_options[*]}"`

Comment: Thanks, that worked!